# [Vue warn]: Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy volviendome loco, estoy intentando combinar Laravel y VueJS. Pero no consigo que funcione. Ayer consegui hacerlo funcionar, pero algo toqué y dejo de hacerlo y ahora no consigo que vuelva a funcionar. El error es este:

**[Vue warn]: Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.**

a ver si me pueden ayudar, adjunto codigo, lo tengo todo en una misma vista:

prueba.blade.php

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

## Pagina de ejemplos

```
<div id="pub">
    <h1 v-text="message"></h1>
    <input type="text" v-model="message">


    <select v-model="categorias">
        <option disabled value="">Seleccione un elemento</option>
        <option >A</option>
        <option >B</option>
        <option >C</option>
    </select>
        {{-- <span>Seleccionado: {{ categorias }}</span> --}}



</div>
@endsection

<script>
    const demo = new Vue({
        el: '#pub',
        data(){
            return {
                message: 'Hola mundo',
                categorias: ''
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué pones la propiedad data como una función?

Comment: El explorador que usas soporta ES6?. Intenta con `data: function() { ....}`

Comment: laravel por defecto monta vuejs por default, porque no creas un componente aparte, mas que el @endsection me da una mala consonante alli,